# How to "automatically" determine values based on date time?

Tags: r

Given the data:

```
      date <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by = "days")
      a<-seq(1,365,1)
      b<- seq(1,365,1)

     df<-data.frame(date,a,b)
```

I would like to extract/subset data from a or b not by determining the date, as for instance, with:

```
   subset<-subset(df, date >= "2014-02-01" & date <= "2014-04-13") # about 69 days
```

but rather:

```
       subset<-subset(df, date= "today"-69 & date= "today")
```

Everytime I run the R-Script it produces a subset between today and 69 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sys.Date()`:

```
subset(df, date >= Sys.Date()-69 & date <= Sys.Date())
[1] date a    b   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Notes:

1. In your example data, you of course have no data from the last 69 days.
2. This is system-dependent so if for some reason you ever ran this on a computer that didn't know what day it was, it might cause you trouble.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thx for your comment. But I dont really understand your first point. Sys.Date() gives me 2015-06-09 with your suggestion I get all my variables with 0 rows...

Comment: @Googme Your example has data from 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31; `Sys.Date()-69` is 2015-04-01, so none of the cases in your `df` data.frame are in the range you've specified.